# How to Use lapply with grep to delete columns in list set

Tags: r, regex, lapply

For the life of me I can't figure out how to `lapply` through my list to grep the column names.

Here is the code that works on one dataframe:

```
tl1 <- trend1[,grep("Date|AIR|LSL",colnames(trend1))]
```

But I have `trend1` through `trend12`. How do I turn this into a list and apply this `grep` to each element of the list to get tl1 through tl12 dataframes?

Alternatively, I would be willing to use a for loop.

Comment: Assuming that you have put trend1 to 12 in a list, then `lapply(list_of_dfs, function(df) df[,grep("Date|AIR|LSL",colnames(df))])` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have `trend1` through `trend12` dataframe in your R environment, you can put them all in one list and use `lapply` to delete the columns you don't need:

```
# mget gets the dataframes whose names are returned by ls
list_of_dfs <- mget(ls(pattern="trend\\d{1,2}"))

# loop through the dataframes and make the changes
new_dfs <- lapply(list_of_dfs, function(df) df[,grep("Date|AIR|LSL",colnames(df))])
```

I hope this helps.